How to expose APIs from occ extension into custom commerce web services?
I have custom commerce webservices extension say "mycommercewebservices" with webroot of "/rest". Now, I want to include APIs from commerce OCC extension (say b2bocc, b2bpunchoutocc, cmsocc etc) into my custom webservices extension and expose these into swagger.
I have tried by including these occ extensions into localextensions.xml but not seeing in swagger (https://my.local:9002/rest/v2/swagger-ui/index.html).
Can anyone let me know what further steps do I need to follow?

I have figured it out. Configure your custom extension to include the OCC controllers from the other extensions. In your web-spring.xml file, import the OCC extension controllers.

You can specify additional web spring contexts in your property files to include extra web contexts
mycustomwebservices.additionalWebSpringConfigs.b2bocc=classpath\:/b2bocc/web/spring/b2bocc-web-spring.xm

